# How to have a mapping in a custom structure inside an ink! contract?

Tags: rust, ink, smart-contract

I'm a newbie with rust and substrate. I'm currently trying to build a PSP34 compatible smart contract (NFT) for documents. In this contract, I'd like to have the following structure:

```
#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Encode, Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub struct DocumentInfo {
    // ...
    /// Mapping to check who has signed
    pub signatures: Mapping<AccountId, ()>,
}
```

Then, in the smart contract, I'm using OpenBrush and it has the following storage definition:

```
    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate, PSP34Storage)]
    pub struct DocumentContract {
        #[PSP34StorageField]
        psp34: PSP34Data,

        // Fields of current contract
        /// mapping from token id to `DocumentInfo`
        document_info: Mapping<Id, DocumentInfo>,
        /// the id of last document
        last_document_id: Id,
        /// ids no longer used (can be reused)
        freed_ids: Vec<Id>,
    }
```

The problem is that the signatures mapping gives me the following error:

```
 | #[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Encode, Decode)]
   |                          ----- in this derive macro expansion
...
53 |     pub signatures: Mapping<AccountId, ()>,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>: WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
  --> traits/document.rs:39:33
   |
39 | #[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Encode, Decode)]
   |                                 ^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Encode` for `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Encode` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>: WrapperTypeDecode` is not satisfied
  --> traits/document.rs:53:5
   |
53 |     pub signatures: Mapping<AccountId, ()>,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeDecode` is not implemented for `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `parity_scale_codec::Decode` for `Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, ()>`
```

I kind of understand what the errors mean, but not really and I have no clue how to fix it. Would appreciate if someone could shine a light on this for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your original question the errors have to do with you trying to derive traits on
your struct which `Mapping` doesn't implement. For example, the [`#[derive(Clone)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#derivable)
macro tries to call `clone()` on every field in the struct - and `Mapping` doesn't
implement `Clone` resulting in the errors you see.

Now, moving on to the `Mapping` inside a `Mapping` situation. It is possible to get the
following to compile:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
pub mod mapper {
    use ink_storage::{
        traits::{
            SpreadAllocate,
            SpreadLayout,
        },
        Mapping,
    };

    type Id = u8;

    #[derive(SpreadAllocate, SpreadLayout)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub struct Map {
        map: Mapping<AccountId, ()>,
    }

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Mapper {
        map: Mapping<Id, Map>,
    }

    impl Mapper {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_| {})
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get(&mut self) {
            // self.map.get(0); <- Doesn't work!
            todo!()
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you try and use this it won't work.

The reason for this is the `Mapping` requires that [values implement `PackedLayout`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/struct.Mapping.html#impl). This
essentially says that the value should be able to be stored in a single storage cell.

`Mapping` itself does not implement `PackedLayout` since it cannot be stored in a single
storage cell. Instead, a `Mapping` is "stored" across many storage cells, each
corresponding to one of the entries in the map (I'm glossing over some details here,
technically `Mapping` isn't stored anywhere).

This is why nested `Mapping`'s are not supported.

You are correct in finding that the best approach here is to use a tuple as a key instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Found the reason for the problem. Basically it is because I'm using a mapping inside a mapping and that is not allowed (https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1175). The solution is to have this information outside the struct as follows:

```
    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate, PSP34Storage)]
    pub struct DocumentContract {
        #[PSP34StorageField]
        psp34: PSP34Data,

        // Fields of current contract
        /// mapping from token id to `DocumentInfo`
        document_info: Mapping<Id, DocumentInfo>,
        /// Mapping with tuple key
        signatures: Mapping<(Id, AccountId), ()>,
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

only developers should answer this question but i have somthings to notice:

1. you can use an `array` instead of `Mapping` for signatures
2. the `DocumentInfo` needs `#[ink(storage)]` and any maps inside of it should be initialized with `ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract` inside `new` or any `constructor` of `DocumentInfo`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason I was trying to use a mapping is because it is more efficient both storage and computational-wise. I've found the reason for my issue.