# Custom Data Struct in Ink!

Tags: ink

I have some questions that about custom data structure in ink!.

https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/faq#what-are-the-scaleencode-and-scaledecode-traits. I already implemented some features with pallet and using the Encode, Decode trait is straight forward to me.

However, there is also a section using some advance storage feature of ink!. https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/datastructures/custom-datastructure

I’m kinda confused that which approach to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have a mapping in a custom structure inside an ink! contract?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-have-a-mapping-in-a-custom-structure-inside-an-ink-contract)

Comment: If not, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I already checked that post, but it not really answered my question What I'm trying to ask is what is the correct way to create a custom struct: "Using `Encode`, `Decode`" or "Implement some storage layout trait". And what the difference between these two approaches.

Comment: As with most design decisions, what you are trying to do (accomplish) is important to drive your tools & techniques used. I meant to ask that above: discuss what you are trying to do so the approach to use can be concretely based on goals.

Comment: The use case is very simple: Have a custom struct and a field with that struct in contract storage.

However, in the past few days, I learnt more about storage layout. So what I guess for the simple use case I describe above: The `Encode`, `Decode` allows serialization, deserialization of a struct into single bytes as we know, which also means that if we don't derive `SpreadLayout` for that custom struct, the default storage layout for that struct is `PackedLayout` and the struct data is packed into one single cell.

Can you confirm this? Because that is exactly what I want to know. @DanShield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `Encode`, `Decode` allows serialization, deserialization of a struct into single bytes as we know, which also means that if we don't derive `SpreadLayout` for that custom struct, the default storage layout for that struct is `PackedLayout` and the struct data is packed into one single cell.

`Encode`/`Decode` does not influence the storage layout ink! uses. By default the struct is `SpreadLayout` ‒ so every struct field is put into its own single storage cell.

This page from the ink! docs has some more details: https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/datastructures/spread-storage-layout.

We're currently working on ink! 4.0 which will greatly simplify the concepts of `SpreadLayout` and `PackedLayout`.

Comment: 1. Can I ask what are the use cases of Encode/Decode if it doesn't influence the storage layout? The only case I can think of is message parameters and returns.

2. I understands `SpreadLayout` but can't understand `SpreadAllocate` and why is it important for `Mapping`. Thanks